# Program halts after while loop fget()

Tags: c, while-loop, fgets

I've been trying to solve this over a few days and it's still doing my head in.  I had a scrappy working program, and decided to clean it up a little, but something's gone wrong in the process.  Part of the program puts csv data (from the file rfile4) into a new file (tmp41) for use later:

```
    FILE *report4=fopen(rfile4,"r");
    FILE *tmp41=fopen(tmpfile41,"w+");

    if(!tmp41||!report4) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "FAILURE - 'REPORT' INPUT FILE NOT FOUND\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const char comma[2]=",";
    int nreports=0;

    while(fgets(line,SIZE,report4)!=NULL)
    {
        char linestore[SIZE];
        char mcodecheck[SIZE];

        strncpy(linestore,line,SIZE);
        char *tkndmp=linestore;

        int count1=0;

        while((tkndmp=strtok(tkndmp,comma))!=NULL)
        {       
            count1++;

            if(count1==4)
            {
                sscanf(tkndmp,"%s",mcodecheck);

                if(strcmp(mcode,mcodecheck)==0)
                {
                   nreports++;
                   fputs(line,tmp41);
                }
            }

            tkndmp=NULL;
        }

    }

    printf("SUCCESS");
    fclose(report4);
    rewind(tmp41);
```

The 'mcode' string is found earlier, and I've confirmed that's right.  All the file locations are also correct.  The data is correctly input into the new file, but the whole program just eternally pauses after the loop, and so I never see 'SUCCESS' printed.

Any ideas?  I had it working previously, the main changes were cleaning up the strtok business, so I suspect I may have made an error with that, or with the pointers.  If I remove all code from within the loop, it exits fine.

Comment: `while(fgets(line,SIZE,report4)!=NULL)` Undeclared identifier: line

Comment: I am sure he didn't post all the code. That would have given a compile error anyway. He says it loops forever (or halts).

Comment: OP: Does the program halt or does it loop forever? Can you put a print inside the while loop to confirm?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tkndmp = strtok(NULL, comma);` where you have `tkndmp=NULL;`?

Comment: ^ That's what I was thinking. He should reset tkndmp to NULL after the first call.

Comment: @Mathieu Rodic Your edit was completely useless. At the least removing `- C`  and condensing the code would be correct. Tags are designed to indicate the language.

Comment: @2501 : sorry, just formatted the title to the usual StackOverflow convention.

Comment: @MathieuRodic ( No need to apologize, keep editing but make some meaningful improvement )The convention is to remove the language from the title and let tags do that.

Comment: @physicsss999 : what do you see if you `printf("%s\n", tkndmp);` in the inner loop, `printf("\n");` in the outer loop and dump the result in a log file?

Comment: What comes after printing "SUCCESS"?  You don't have a newline or an `fflush` there so the "SUCCESS" won't actually be printed until the next newline.  I suggest you put a newline in there and maybe you'll find your code is hanging later on.

Comment: @cursillosonline that is exactly what the next iteration of the while-condition will do once `tkdmp = NULL;` is done at the bottom of the loop. The next iteration of `while((tkndmp=strtok(tkndmp,comma))!=NULL)` thusly becomes equivalent to `while((tkndmp=strtok(NULL,comma))!=NULL)`

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I can't believe I've been so stupid in wasting time looking at something which is actually fine.  JS1 nailed it, I forgot that nothing is printed unless a newline appears, the hang up is indeed further down.  The program was getting held up due to a typo in a for loop a fair way down.

Comment: For anyone wondering about the strtok loops, I picked that up from a thread here in terms of cleaning things up - my original code for said loops was the equivalent, as WhozCraig posted:

    `tkndmp=strtok(line,comma);  
    while(tkndmp!=NULL)
    {...stuff...
    tkndmp=strtok(NULL,comma)}`

Comment: @physicsss999 Suggest posting your own answer and accepting it to close this post.

Comment: [`strncpy()` is not a safer `strcpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New line required to print line to string.

Comment: This needs to be rephrased; what does "print line to string" mean?